# Is extraction counted as a round?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

In Mass Effect 3 there are some map challenges like "Complete 100 rounds at map X on difficulty Y". Every game consists of 10 rounds and an extraction round. Does this extraction round count towards the challenge?  If yes, what happens if you don't extract for whatever reason, but a subset of the rest of the team does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, extraction does not count as a round.

This is part of the reason why some people drop out during that phase. If they're just going for round gains there's no reason for them to spend the time in extraction.

Comment: Of course, they won't get extraction badges if they drop out early...

Comment: True. They also get yelled at, but they're no longer there to hear it.